# How to construct a Wiener-like process on Tori?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

That means the process may be periodic by distribution. And in what condition could the process be present as a series of Fourier bases multiplied by random variables?

Answer (score 0):

Brownian motion on a manifold starts with constructing the heat equation problem on it. One main reference is [Stochastic Analysis On Manifolds](https://sayanmuk.github.io/StochasticAnalysisManifolds.pdf).

As mentioned in Example 4.34 [Heat Equation and Brownian Motion on
Riemannian Manifolds](https://studenttheses.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/20.500.12932/40182/Bachelor%20Thesis%20Bart%20Heemskerk%20Final.pdf?sequence=1), the transition density on the torus $\mathbb{T}^{n}:=\mathbb{R}^{n}/\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ is

$$\large p_{\mathbb{T}^{n}}(x,y,t):=\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^{n}}e^{-\|y'+m-x'\|^{2}/4t},$$

where for $\pi:\mathbb R^{n}\to\mathbb{T}^{n}$, we let $x',y'$ be two representatives such that $\pi(x')=x,\pi(y')=y$ and $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean-norm.